# Points on triangle median forming isosceles triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyEpi.png)

Let $\triangle ABC$ be a triangle and M the center of $\overline{AB}$. On the median $\overline{CM}$ a point D is chosen so that $\overline{CD}=\overline{AD}$ and a point E so that $\overline{CE}=\overline{EB}$. Now choose a point F such that $\angle FAC=\angle MAD$. Prove: Then also $\angle CBF=\angle EBM. $

I have so far tried to use the Law of sines to exploit the fact that $\overline{AM}=\overline{MB}$. I also found out that $\angle MAC=\angle AFD$, which is relatively easy to prove. Obviously $\angle ACD=\angle MAF$ holds as well. Nevertheless, I could not solve the problem as a whole yet.

Comment: I think you have good progress. From your angle relations, show that $\triangle ACM \sim \triangle FAM$, then show that some corresponding sides are proportional, then show that on the other side of the median $\triangle BCM\sim \triangle FBM$. What remains are like the reverse of your progress.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}
\angle MAC &= \angle MAD + \angle DAC\\
&= \angle FAC + \angle ACD &&\text{Given; Base angles, } AD=CD\\
&= \angle MFA&&\text{External angles of triangle}\\
\angle CMA &= \angle AMF && \text{Common}\\
\triangle ACM &\sim \triangle FAM &&\text{AAA}\\
\frac{CM}{AM} &= \frac{AM}{FM} &&\text{Corresponding sides}\\
\frac{CM}{BM} &= \frac{BM}{FM} &&\text{Given } AM=BM\\
\angle CMB &= \angle BMF &&\text{Common}\\
\triangle BCM &\sim \triangle FBM &&\text{Corresponding sides and included } \angle\\
\angle FBM &= \angle BCM &&\text{Corresponding }\angle\\
&= \angle CBE &&\text{Base angles, } CE=EB\\
\angle FBE+\angle EBM &= \angle CBF+\angle FBE\\
\angle EBM &= \angle CBF
\end{align*}$$